# Append xml string into Existing xmlfile using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml like this :

```
<name>

<class>

</class>

</name>
```

then i want to add the tag like this

```
<tia:Demographic><Age/><DOB/></tia:Demographic>
```

in between

```
<class>
```

How can we do that .

i am using following code.

```
XDoc.LoadXml(@"<name><class></class></name>");   
XmlDocumentFragment xfrag = XDoc.CreateDocumentFragment(); 
 xfrag.InnerXml = @"<tia:Demographic><Age/><DOB/></tia:Demographic>";
 XDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(xfrag); 
XDoc.Save(@"D:\test.xml");
```

but it throws an error that tia: not a registered namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to register a namespace:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(@"<name><class></class></name>");
        xdoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:tia", "http://tia.com");
        var node = xdoc.CreateElement("tia", "Demographic", "http://tia.com");
        var xfrag = xdoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        xfrag.InnerXml = @"<Age/><DOB/>";
        node.AppendChild(xfrag);
        xdoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(node);
        xdoc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Register the namespace using a [XmlNamespaceManager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545) .